# Where does nginx store default error pages

Tags: nginx

Where does `nginx` store the default error pages it outputs on disk? I.E. the standard `404` looking like:

404 Not Found

## 404 Not Found

---

nginx

Hopefully these are **not** hard-coded into the nginx source. Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Check out html folder in the nginx directory - there should be 50x pages.

By default, I believe, all "special pages", including 404 page are *hardcoded*

```c
static char ngx_http_error_404_page[] =
"<html>" CRLF
"<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>" CRLF
"<body>" CRLF
"<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>" CRLF
;
```

Source: https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/release-1.15.8/src/http/ngx_http_special_response.c#L132

but can be customized:

```
server {
    ...
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Links shouldn't be used as answers because, surprise surprise, pages disappear, your answer is now incomplete because that page no longer exists

Comment: Updated the answer with specific instructions

Comment: Thanks, changed my feedback accordingly

Comment: Updated the answer with link to official repo and code excerpt

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the operating system and so forth, but for Ubuntu the default error pages are usually located in the `/usr/share/nginx/html` directory...

Here's a good overview on customizing them:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-to-use-custom-error-pages-on-ubuntu-22-04

You can also change the directory by altering the `root` directive.

For example:

```
server {
    ...
    
    error_page 404 /custom_404.html;
    location = /custom_404.html {
        root /custom/directory/for/error_pages;
        internal;
    }

...
}
```